# Winding number of center symmetries

Tags: symmetry, gauge-theory, topology

Suppose we have a center symmetry transformation that acts on the connection as:
$$A \mapsto \ ^gA = \Omega^{-1} (A+d)\Omega $$
and satisfies
$$ \Omega(t+\beta,x) = h\Omega(t,x)$$

Suppose $W[U]$ represents the winding number of $U$ a gauge transformation, which is an integer, and is computed as:

$$ W[U] = \frac{1}{24 \pi^2} \int d^3x \ \epsilon^{\mu \nu \beta} \ \text{Tr}(U \partial_{\mu} U^{-1} \ U \partial_{\nu} U^{-1} \ U \partial_{\beta} U^{-1})$$

What can we say about $W[\Omega]$? Is it also an integer. Note that this is not immediate since $\Omega$ does not need to be continuous.

Comment: What do you mean by winding number? Center symmetries are parametrized by connections in the center of the gauge group.

Comment: @RyanThorngren, what I am asking is, what happens if we put $\Omega$ in the formula for the winding number. Is it an integer. I will edit the question.